# Bootstrap not showing correctly in Atom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, atom-editor

I'm relatively new so apologies if this is a very basic question but I am trying to create a site using Atom text editor and the Bootstrap Yeti theme pulled from Bootswatch.

I've taken a copy of the style sheet and saved it referencing as normal in the HTML, it's reading and applying the style but it not showing quite right.

I have tried in a couple of other tools - JS fiddle - and its showing exactly as I would expect.

Again sorry if this is a very basic question but I'm still learning

Any help would be great

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
        <title>Clarity Analysis Ltd Landing Page</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Volumes/HD-Documents/Atom/Clarity Analysis/css/flatley.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Volumes/HD-Documents/Atom/Clarity Analysis/css/landingcustom.css">
  </head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Jumbotron</h1>
  <p>This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have problems with Atom or is it just that the result is not what you expected on the browser?

Comment: Without seeing your code, we are unable to help.

Comment: Atom itself seems to be working really well, it's just the preview is not what I expected. The navbar and buttons aren't looking right. I did try and attach a picture but it wouldnt let me.

Comment: Found a test app here and also showing as I expect just not int he editor

Comment: @WRussell Did you try what Olivier have suggested?

Comment: I have yeah but still doesn't look right - I know this will be a pretty basic issues I've missed just frustrating

Answer (score 0):

You are not including bootstraps css and js

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="whereever/bootstrap.css" media="screen">
```

and on the bottom your page

```
<script src="whereever/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi - thanks I've linked them both up, css in head and js at the bottom just before i close the body tag, still not styling as it should